How to track the number of interaction points until a key event?
The task is to export associated conversions from GA4.
I cannot obtain this metric via the GA4 API.
I am writing everything in Python, and I have gone through all the analytics documentation but found nothing indicating the interaction points.
screen ga4

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The bot is right. Add more details. Your question makes no sense. Everything in GA4 is an interaction one way or another. The details about those interactions are stored in the fields. Normally meaningfull details are in the event parameters field. It's called event_params If I remember correctly. It contains event parameters as json. Great design. Json in SQL. Great job, Google.

I'm going into the attribution path and I need to get the chain of the user's path through the API
